# How to access value of switchable fieldType dialog in magnolia 6.2 using .ftl languange

Tags: dialog, yaml, freemarker, magnolia

FYI I'm new in magnolia,
I'm trying to use switchable type field in dialog, here is my YAML look like :

```html
form:
  label: Confirmation Pop Up
  tabs:
    - name: Menu
      label: Menu
      fields:        
        - name: linkUrl
          fieldType: switchable
          label: Link Button Reject
          class: info.magnolia.ui.field.ConfiguredSwitchableFieldDefinition
          transformerClass: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.transformer.composite.SwitchableTransformer
          options:
            - name: intLink
              label: Internal URL
              selected: true
              value: intLink
            - name: extLink
              label: External URL
              value: extLink

          fields:
            - name: intLink
              class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.LinkFieldDefinition
              targetWorkspace: website
              fieldType: link
              appName: pages
              label: Link Internal
              description: Choose a page to link .
              identifierToPathConverter:
                class: info.magnolia.dam.app.ui.field.definition.DamUploadFieldDefinition

            - name: extLink 
              label: Link External 
              class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition

               
actions:
  commit:
    class: info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.dialog.action.SaveDialogActionDefinition
  cancel:
    class: info.magnolia.ui.admincentral.dialog.action.CancelDialogActionDefinition
```

I can get this value

```html
options:
  - name: intLink
    label: Internal URL
    selected: true
    value: intLink
  - name: extLink
    label: External URL
    value: extLink
```

by calling ${content.linkUrl} which will show "intLink" or "extLink",

so, how do I get value of this :

```html
fields:
  - name: intLink
    class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.LinkFieldDefinition
    targetWorkspace: website
    fieldType: link
    appName: pages
    label: Link Internal
    description: Choose a page to link .
    identifierToPathConverter:
       class: info.magnolia.dam.app.ui.field.definition.DamUploadFieldDefinition

  - name: extLink 
    label: Link External 
    class: info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.TextFieldDefinition
```

Could anyone help me on this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the JCR for that node you'll probably see an item called `linkUrlintLink` and `linkUrlextLink` This is because the values aren't getting transformed and by default, the switchable field will concatenate the names. You should be able to access them through `${content.linkUrlintLink` and `${content.linkUrlextLink`. You also can use the `DelegatingCompositeFieldTransformer` class to strip the prepended name of the field names.

Comment: thanks so much, it works,
I also found the article about DelegatingCompositeFieldTransformer 
https://docs.magnolia-cms.com/product-docs/6.2/Support/Magnolia-5-UI-documentation/Dialog-definition-5-UI/Field-definition-5-UI/Transforming-field-values-5-UI.html#_delegatingcompositefieldtransformer

I'll save it here